# How to get fields inside message array from Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I've been trying to configure a logstash pipeline with input type is snmptrap along with yamlmibdir. Here's the code

```
input {
  snmptrap {
    host => "abc"
    port => 1062
    yamlmibdir => "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/snmp-1.3.2/data/ruby/snmp/mibs"
  }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message","^\"{","{"]
        gsub => ["message","}\"$","}"]
        gsub => ["message","[\\]",""]
   }

    json { source => "message" }
    split {
        field => "message"
        target => "evetns"
          }
    }

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "xyz"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

and the result shown in Kibana (JSON format)

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2019.11.18-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "Y_5zjG4B6M9gb7sxUJwG",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2019-11-21T05:33:07.675Z",
    "tags": [
      "_jsonparsefailure"
    ],
    "1.11.12.13.14.15": "teststring",
    "message": "#<SNMP::SNMPv1_Trap:0x244bf33f @enterprise=[1.2.3.4.5.6], @timestamp=#<SNMP::TimeTicks:0x196a1590 @value=55>, @varbind_list=[#<SNMP::VarBind:0x21f5e155 @name=[1.11.12.13.14.15], @value=\"teststring\">], @specific_trap=99, @source_ip=\"xyz\", @agent_addr=#<SNMP::IpAddress:0x5a5c3c5f @value=\"xC0xC1xC2xC3\">, @generic_trap=6>",
    "host": "xyz"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-11-21T05:33:07.675Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1574314387675
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the message field, it's an array so how can I get all the field inside the array. also able to select these field to display on Kibana.

ps1. still got tags _jsonparsefailure if select type 'Table' in Expanded document 
ps2. even if using gsub for remove '\' from expected json result, why still got an result with '\' ?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the kv filter, which is to parse key-value structure, like the one in your message

Comment: Which part of your message is in json format?

Comment: Your original message is not a JSON, why are you using the json filer? You need to build a grok filter to parse the snmp message or you could try to use the snmp input filter, this will logstash will poll the snmp data from the device and parse it, instead of listening for the data.